# Lua: get POST data

Tags: lua, openresty

I'm receiving this JSON in the POST data:

```
{
    "foo":{
        "hi": "there",
        "hello": "world"
    }
}
```

In Lua, I want to get *foo* in order to save it in Redis, so it'd be great to save it as an string.

How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install [json-lua](https://github.com/jiyinyiyong/json-lua) or [lua-cjson](http://www.kyne.com.au/~mark/software/lua-cjson-manual.html) packages first. Then, parse the JSON response (received as `string`) and it gets converted to a table.

Using `pairs()` you can iterate over key-values of the table generated above.

---

OpenResty already bundles a fork of [`lua-cjson`](https://openresty.org/en/lua-cjson-library.html) with it.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is `s`, then this extracts the value of `foo`:

```
print(s:match('"foo"%s*:%s*(%b{})'))
```